# Decomposition of a positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Let $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a symmetric, positive semidefinite matrix such that $Y_{kk} = 1$ for all $k$.

This matrix is supposed to be factorized as $Y = V^T V$, where $V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

- Does this factorization/decomposition have a name?
- How is it possible to compute $V$?

Comment: > Does this factorization/decomposition have a name?
ANSWER.

At some sources $Y=V^T V$ (in real case) or $Y=V^* V$ (in complex case) is called just PSD decomposition.


Also, the fact that $Y=V^T V=W^T W$ iff $C=QW$ for an orthogonal $Q$ is sometimes called orthogonal freedom.
And the fact that $Y=V^* V=W^* W$ iff $C=QW$ for an unitary $Q$ is sometimes called unitary freedom.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If $\rm Y$ is **symmetric**, then it is diagonalizable, its eigenvalues are real, and its eigenvectors are orthogonal. Hence, $\rm Y$ has an eigendecomposition $\rm Y = Q \Lambda Q^{\top}$, where the columns of $\rm Q$ are the eigenvectors of $\rm Y$ and the diagonal entries of diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ are the eigenvalues of $\rm Y$.

If $\rm Y$ is also **positive semidefinite**, then all its eigenvalues are nonnegative, which means that we can take their square roots. Hence,

$$\rm Y = Q \Lambda Q^{\top} = Q \Lambda^{\frac 12} \Lambda^{\frac 12} Q^{\top} = \underbrace{\left( Q \Lambda^{\frac 12} \right)}_{=: {\rm V}} \left( Q \Lambda^{\frac 12} \right)^{\top} = V^{\top} V$$

Note that the rows of $\rm V$ are the eigenvectors of $\rm Y$ multiplied by the square roots of the (nonnegative) eigenvalues of $\rm Y$.

Comment: You are right, the matrix is symmetric, I have not noticed it. I've added it to the problem description. I try to decompose it as you said. Thanks

Comment: Why can you not take the square root when the matrix is positive semidefinite?

Comment: @JohnK You can. I assumed positive definiteness because $\rm V$ is square.

Comment: @JohnK I edited my answer. I can live with $\rm V$ having rows full of zeros.

Comment: Is anything known about the uniqueness of this decomposition? If I have a symmetric psd matrix C such that $C=AA^T=BB^T$ then can we say something about relation between A and B?

Comment: @avk255 It should not be unique. One can always permute the columns of $\rm Q$ and the corresponding diagonal entries of $\Lambda$.

Comment: Wikipedia says: _"Y is positive definite if and only if such a decomposition exists with V invertible. "_  Does this mean, in the above case V is also invertible? (just to confirm)

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_symmetric_matrix#Decomposition

Comment: @Ufos If $\rm Y$ is only positive semidefinite, $\Lambda$ will have zero diagonal entries and, thus, $\rm V$ cannot be invertible.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yeah, right, the article also specifies the matrix must be hermitian, of which symmetric is a special case. So, in such case, V still will be invertible?

Comment: @Ufos The zero square matrix is also Hermitian. The OP mentioned that the matrix is real, and I am not so familiar with complex matrices.