# What is the proof behind positive definite matrix $A=QQ^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite

I read this a lot of times, but I can't seem to prove it. How does a positive definite matrix $A$ decompose to $QQ^T$?

Comment: Look at the associated quadratic form, and repeatedly "complete the square".

Comment: Not every positive definite matrix is orthogonal.

Comment: Use the spectral decomposition and then take the square roots of the (positive) eigenvalues. Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1801403/339790).

Comment: You may also repeatedly "remove squares" (as opposed to completing square). This results in Cholesky decomposition.